# InspIRCd doesn’t even contact configured LDAP

Tags: ldap, authentication, openldap, irc, inspircd

On Ubuntu 20.04 I've installed InspIRCd (which seems to work fine as-is) and added to its config:

```
<module name="m_ldapauth.so">
<ldapauth baserdn="dc=nodomain"
          attribute="cn"
          server="ldap://127.0.0.1"
          killreason="nice try"
          searchscope="subtree"
          binddn="cn=admin,dc=nodomain"
          bindauth="123456"
          verbose="yes"
          userfield="no" >
```

According to Wireshark the client sends PASS 123456 and NICK aklimov, but the server kicks me out (w/ "nice try"). Even more strange: according to Wireshark (-f port 389) there's no LDAP traffic at all.

Comment: is ldap listening on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Even on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: so can you login with ldapsearch and get results?

Comment: I've even created aklimov:123456 w/ phpldapadmin.

Comment: that's not the answer to my question ;), what I mean is, can you use a ldap client, like the cli tool ldapsearch, to log in and get results to ldap://127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: The phpldapadmin client also lists.. everything to me.

Comment: could you try this on the inspircd host: ldapsearch -x -b dc=nodomain -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -D cn=admin,dc=nodomain -W  and post the results back?

Comment: also, I have zero experience with this irc software, but according to the docs (https://docs.inspircd.org/3/modules/ldapauth/) you should use <module name="ldapauth"> instead of <module name="m_ldapauth.so">

Comment: ```
dn: dc=nodomain
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: nodomain
dc: nodomain

dn: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9cTBVYmk1SFVwbEszTW9lczlQckl0U1IyaHdRTVE3RC8=

dn: cn=aklimov,dc=nodomain
cn: aklimov
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9OFdpNUdBZUJvM21TUUkvbTRNdHdtYWtnMVArYkJtNjQ=
sn: Klimov

search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

Comment: `<module name="ldapauth">` gives the same result.

Comment: could you try this: ldapsearch -x -b dc=nodomain -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -D cn=admin,dc=nodomain -W cn? So I want to see only the cn attribute

Comment: # nodomain
dn: dc=nodomain
 
# admin, nodomain
dn: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
cn: admin
 
# aklimov, nodomain
dn: cn=aklimov,dc=nodomain
cn: aklimov
 
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
                                                                                                                                                                                             
# numResponses: 4                                                                                                                                                                           
# numEntries: 3

Comment: thanks, looks like the ldap host is working, so the issue must lie inside the application itself. Time to open an issue at https://github.com/inspircd/inspircd/issues